# Copy and rename worksheets from a list using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. I have found code that copy and rename multiple template worksheets based on a list in a column (A1, A2, A3 etc).  I tried modifying it to loop through a row instead, ie cells A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, but no luck.  I want to copy multiple templates and rename them based on an account number entered via a user input form. I have created a worksheet, LedgerArray, that lists worksheet names for each account number.  Example:

```
row1: 1Savings, 1Shares, 1Statement
row2: 2Savings, 2Shares, 2Statement
```

Thanks in advance

Hello Ambie,   your effort is much appreciated, fluey infant especially.   I developed the code below.  It works as far as copying and renaming the templates, and assigning user input to specific template header cells.  These tasks are intended for new accounts.  A separate user form is intended for existing accounts.  As you indicated, no error handling procedures are included (eg entry of a duplicate account number).  Also, the section of the code that should transfer share transaction data to the first empty row in the renamed worksheet does not work.  When executed, the code returns no syntax error but the result on the first empty row is blank.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Template As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String, str4 As String, str5 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lrShar As Long, lrSav As Long, lrTD As Long, lrStmnt As Long
    str1 = "Shares"
    str2 = "Savings"
    str3 = "TimeDeposit"
    str4 = "Loans"
    str5 = "Statements"

    'hide the form
    frmAddSheet.Hide

    'Select 1st template
    Template = "TemplateShares"

    'copy template to create a new sheet
    Sheets(Template).Select
    Sheets(Template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = AccNumTextBox & str1

    'Transfer Heading data
    Set ws = Sheets(AccNumTextBox & str1)
    ws.Range("A4") = AccNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B5") = DTPicker4.Value
    ws.Range("B6") = Reference.Value
    ws.Range("B7") = RegFeeTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B8") = NameTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B9") = AddressTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B10") = TelNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B11") = EmailTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B12") = ComboBox2.Value
    ws.Range("B13") = DOBDTPicker.Value

    'transfer Share transaction data
    lrShar = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lrShar).Value = DTPicker4.Value
    ws.Range("B" & lrShar).Value = Reference.Value
    ws.Range("C" & lrShar).Value = SharesTextBox.Value

    'Select 2nd template
    Template = "TemplateSavings"

    'copy template to create a new sheet
    Sheets(Template).Select
    Sheets(Template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = AccNumTextBox & str2

    'Transfer Heading data
    Set ws = Worksheets(AccNumTextBox & str2)
    ws.Range("A4") = AccNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B5") = DTPicker4.Value
    ws.Range("B6") = Reference.Value
    ws.Range("B7") = RegFeeTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B8") = NameTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B9") = AddressTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B10") = TelNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B11") = EmailTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B12") = ComboBox2.Value
    ws.Range("B13") = DOBDTPicker.Value

    'Select 3rd template
    Template = "TemplateTimeDeposit"

    'copy template to create a new sheet
    Sheets(Template).Select
    Sheets(Template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = AccNumTextBox & str3

    'Transfer Heading data
    Set ws = Worksheets(AccNumTextBox & str3)
    ws.Range("A4") = AccNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B5") = DTPicker4.Value
    ws.Range("B6") = Reference.Value
    ws.Range("B7") = RegFeeTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B8") = NameTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B9") = AddressTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B10") = TelNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B11") = EmailTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B12") = ComboBox2.Value
    ws.Range("B13") = DOBDTPicker.Value

    'Select 4th template
    Template = "TemplateLoans"

    'copy template to create a new sheet
    Sheets(Template).Select
    Sheets(Template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = AccNumTextBox & str4

    'Select 5th template
    Template = "TemplateStatement"

    'copy template to create a new sheet
    Sheets(Template).Select
    Sheets(Template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = AccNumTextBox & str5

    'Transfer Heading data
    Set ws = Worksheets(AccNumTextBox & str5)
    ws.Range("B8") = AccNumTextBox.Value
    ws.Range("B9") = DTPicker4.Value
    ws.Range("B10") = NameTextBox.Value


    'Bring Data Entry sheet back to front if necesary
    If chkBringToFront = False Then
        Sheets("DataEntry").Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you modify the code? What happened when you ran it?

Comment: If you arrange your data in a column, does the original code do what you want?  Within the loop you will find Cells(X, Y) or Range("Y" & X).  In both cases X is a row number.  In both cases Y identifies a column but can be a letter or a number with A=1, B=2, C=3 and so on.  In the current code Y will be fixed and X will depend on the loop variable.  You need to reverse the Cells or Range so the row is fixed and the column depends with the loop variable.

Comment: What code did you try to change? Can you post what code you do have?  And to clarify: you have a list of sheet names in "Workbook1, worksheet1", and you want to copy and rename other worksheets (in "Workbook2, worksheet1" let's say) to "Workbook1", renaming each page in order of your list?

Comment: Sorry Amy, the code worked well but I discarded it because it didn't do what I needed. It was copied and pasted from another site and assumed the list was column based. I am using  one workbook.

Comment: Tony, i'm a complete novice.  I really don't know what to do. I am thinking there may be a better way of doing what i want, such as using a numerical variable (obtained from user input) to create worksheet names.  Thi variable would be part of a string in the worksheet name ( eg 00001Savings, 00002Savings)

Comment: Sorry everyone, I may not be clear on the situation. We are an emerging non-profit endeavor, a financial cooperative.  For each member, a unique account number is assigned from which ledgers are generated, such as 00001Savings, 00001Shares, 00001Statement.  The next account would generate worksheets named 00002Savings, 00002Shares, 00002Statements, etc. In summary I want to automate the process of copying the templates (templateSavings, templateShares,etc) for each account number generated by user input (data input)

Comment: Excel is not the right tool for building an accounting system.  I will not be placing any of my savings with an organisation that using untrained people to write an accounting system with an unsuitable tool.  There are many excellent packages available to buy or "rent".  Is their purchase/rental price so much more than your salary?  Who will carry the can when your system fails as it undoubtedly will since you are not trained to write robust software.

Comment: That is a good point Tony.  It is voluntary work being done in Africa.  Can you recommend a good 'tool'?

Comment: I have never wanted to set up a credit union, or whatever this is, and have never investigated what relevant packages are available.  My main point is that building a robust accounting system is not easy and you are totally unqualified to build one.  Would you build a bridge or perform surgery on the basis of bits and pieces picked up from the web?  Talk to a credit union in your own country. Where did they get their system?  Perhaps they would be willing to help you for the kudos.

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to VBA, I've given an example that uses some aspects you might find useful in your coding future (a class and a collection).

Create a new class and call it cTemplate. Add the following properties:

```
Public Original As Worksheet
Public Suffix As String
```

Declare this module-level variable (ie at the top of your programme).

```
Private mTemplateList As Collection
```

Populate a collection with your template objects. (Note I've done this in a routing called "Initialise". If you don't have something similar then just call this routine in your Workbook_Open event).

I'd prefer to keep control of the template names, so you'll see that I've added them manually. In response to your question though, I've put a routine below it that reads the first row of a worksheet and takes out the template name, but it has no error handling and if anything should change in that list, your entire worksheet naming structure will be messed up.

```
Sub Initialise()
    '
    ' /.../
    '
    Dim template As cTemplate


    ' Populate the collection with template and clone names.
    Set mTemplateList = New Collection

    Set template = New cTemplate
    Set template.Original = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("templateSavings")
    template.Suffix = "Savings"
    mTemplateList.Add template

    Set template = New cTemplate
    Set template.Original = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("templateShares")
    template.Suffix = "Shares"
    mTemplateList.Add template

    Set template = New cTemplate
    Set template.Original = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("templateStatements")
    template.Suffix = "Statements"
    mTemplateList.Add template

    '
    ' Or if you really must read a row of previous worksheet names
    ' and you are certain the first row contains "1" then sheet name,
    ' use the following
    '
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    dim str as String

    Set mTemplateList = New Collection

    ' Quick and nasty row 1 selection -
    ' Adjust as you require for your own rows.
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Resize(1)

    ' Read each cell to obtain the template sheet name
    ' Assumes each name has "1" and "template" at the start
    For Each cell In rng.Columns
        Set template = New cTemplate
        str = Replace(cell.Text, "1", "")
        Set template.Original = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str)
        str = Replace(str, "template", "")
        template.Suffix = str
        mTemplateList.Add template
    Next

End Sub
```

And finally, when a user adds a new account number, call the following routine.

```
Sub CreateNewTemplates(accountNumber As Long)
    Dim template As cTemplate
    Dim accountPrefix As String
    Dim lastSheet As Worksheet

    ' Create prefix for worksheet names
    accountPrefix = Format(accountNumber, "00000")

    ' Loop through the templates to copy
    Set lastSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    For Each template In mTemplateList

        template.Original.Copy After:=lastSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = accountPrefix & template.Suffix
        Set lastSheet = ActiveSheet

    Next
End Sub
```

Worksheet objects need careful error handling and your routine will need to check for duplicate account names, missing templates, etc. The same applies to your row reader for worksheet names. I'm afraid I'm typing at night with a fluey infant on my lap and she's just stirring, so I'll leave that bit for you.